# How can I have a javascript animation sit in a div

Tags: javascript, html, animation

So say I have the following bit of javascript animation:

```
window.onload = function (){
    var paper = new Raphael( 0, 0, 800, 600);
    var backGround = paper.rect(0,0,800,600);
    backGround.attr({ fill: "blue"});

    var ball = paper.circle(50,50,30);
    ball.attr({ fill: "45-orange-yellow"});

    function bounce_up1(){
        ball.animate({cy: 50,cx: 750}, 1000,'ease-out',bounce_drop2);   
    }

    function bounce_drop1(){
            ball.animate({cy: 570,cx: 400}, 1000, 'ease-in', bounce_up1);   
    }

    function bounce_up2(){
        ball.animate({cy: 50,cx: 50}, 1000,'ease-out',bounce_drop1);    
    }

    function bounce_drop2(){
        ball.animate({cy: 570,cx: 400}, 1000, 'ease-in', bounce_up2);   
    }

    bounce_drop1();

};
```

And I want it to sit inside the "Animation" Div in this HTML5 code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="raphael-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bounce.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tom Wija's Coursework</title>
<link href="styles/coursework.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="header"><h1>Thomas Wija: Coursework</h1></div>
  <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CV</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hobbies</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Past Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Animation</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="animation">
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I wanted the javascript animation bounce.js to nest inside the animation div rather than just render at the top right hand corner of the screen like it does at the moment, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Without running your code I can't see how those elements are being placed. But if they are being positioned absolutely then set the containing div to position relative. Then anything that is positioned absolutely is within that 'relative' div. otherwise use a canvas?